# ¿Guardar cambios del DOM con javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, dom, local-storage

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web pero tengo un problema. hay unos elementos en un array, es un array de objetos. Cada posición tiene su nombre, precio etc. Los he listado mostrando sus datos, ya lo hice pero ahora le agregué un botón a cada uno, y como se repite, se los agrega a todos.

Lo que quiero es que cuando les de clic al botón que se cambie de color del elemento pero solo de ese, no de todos, y que aparte cuando cargue la página nuevamente ese cambio se quede guardado, estaba pensando en `localstorage` pero no sé cómo.

```
articulos.map((item) =>(
    <div key={item["Id"]} className="targeta">
        <div className="img-articulo">
            <img src={ruta+item["Imagen"]} alt="imagen-articulo"/>
        </div>

        <h2>{item["Titulo"]}</h2>
        <p>{item["Descripcion"]}</p>
        <h1>${item["Precio"]}</h1>
        
        <div className={cont_canti+item["Id"]}> 
            <NumericInput 
              id={item["Id"]}
              className="form-control " 
              value={1} 
              min={1} 
              max={10} 
              step={1} 
              precision={0} 
              size={2} 
              mobile
              />
        </div>
      
        <button type="button" className={item["Id"]} onClick={()=>{Ajax(item["Id"])}}>Reservar</button>
        <Link to="/Carrito" id="btn-carrito" className={btncarrito+item["Id"]}>Ver carrito</Link>
    </div>
));
```

Lo que he podido hacer esta ahora es cambiar el estilo de cada elemento pero la idea es guardar ese estilo localmente o de otra forma que cuando refresque la página, siga los estilos aplicados.

AQUÍ LLAMA CADA VEZ QUE SE DA CLIC AL BOTÓN

```
function Ajax(id){ 
    var cant = document.getElementById(id).value;
  
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("GET","http://localhost/ecomerce/ecommerce-pizza/src/Api/Ajax.php?id="+id+"&cant="+cant,true);
      
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){

            var get = localStorage.getItem("cantidad");
            localStorage.setItem("cantidad",Number(cant)+Number(get));
            console.log(this.responseText);
       
        }

    }
    http.send();

    document.getElementsByClassName(id)[0].style.display="none";
    document.getElementsByClassName("cantidad"+id)[0].style.display="none";
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn-carrito"+id)[0].style.display="block";
       
    
}
```

No le pongan atención a la respuesta del AJAX, eso es aparte.

La función Ajax está agregando ese dato guardado en un archivo JSON pero después de eso es lo importante, que es intentar con clases cambiar su estilo.

SERÍA DE GRAN AYUDA QUE ALGUIEN ME DIERA UNA RESPUESTA.

Comment: Hola @YOSIP. Trata de compartir tu código para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Listo amigo ya lo actualice

Comment: Queres que al darle click al boton de un articulo cambie el color del boton de ese articulo?

Comment: Hay 2 botones uno esta oculto y el otro se muestra, La idea es que cuando le de click al botón que se muestra ese desaparezca y el que esta oculto se muestre. Es como un carrito el primer botón dice agregar y el que esta oculto dirá agregado pero necesito que se quede guardado en la página.

Comment: Supongo que con "al otro boton" te referis al <Link> no?

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es que le estas asignando mal la clase al poner `className={btncarrito+item["Id"]}` no le estas pasando el valor del id del Item, si no que le estas pasando literalmente `+item["Id"]` como string, no como valor del id del item, para solucionarlo podrias usar los Template literals (su sintaxis es: `${expression}`) para que te tome el valor del id en si y no como un string.

```
<Link style={{display: 'none'}} to="/Carrito" id="btn-carrito" className={`btncarrito${item['Id']}`}>
    Ver carrito
</Link>
```

luego en tu método `Ajax` obtienes el elemento y le pones el display block, para que se muestre.

```
const button = document.getElementsByClassName(`btncarrito${id}`)[0];
button.style.display = 'block';
```